# Grails filters: can uri and uriExclude be used in the same filter?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-filters

I've defined a filter in grails like so:

```
securityFilter(uri: '/api/**', uriExclude: '/api/**/*skipthis*') {
   before {
       ...
       println request.url
   }
}
```

I was expecting it to handle any requests like `/api/mything` but ignore requests like `/blahblah/mything/` and `/api/mything/andskipthisthing` requests yet my log reveals it's dutifully looking at `/blahblah/mything`

I understand that excludes take precedence, but I would have thought that would mean it would still only look at anything under `/api/`.  I haven't seen any examples of `excludeUri` in my searches, and all the `uri` examples I see only use the `uri` and nothing else.  Are we allowed to use `excludeUri` and `uri` together?  Is this a bug in grails?

Answer (score 0):

Doh!  I was looking at `request.requestURL`, which is the grails dispatcher url (ends with `.dispatch`) ... What I wanted was the `request.forwardURI`